# What is the difference between a Sub-Charter Flight and a Codeshare Flight?

Tags: airline-operations

What are the main differences of this two types of flights?

Comment: I don't know if it still applies, but back in the 1990s a codeshare flight was a regularly scheduled flight of a single aircraft identified by the flight numbers of two different carriers, both of which sold tickets for the flight. A sub-service flight, which I'm guessing that sub-charter refers to, was when airline A called airline B, often on short notice, and said something like, we don't have an airplane for our flight 1234 Montreal to JFK. Can you cover it for us. That's often expensive for airline A because of empty positioning legs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub charter is not used nowadays as a word expression. It's now called wet lease or ACMI. An ACMI specialist airline does not fly its own regular schedule, but usually flies for other airlines on shorter/longer notices (couple of flights or whole schedule). When WOW air started in Iceland, its schedule was flown by a Lithuanian ACMI operator. HiFly flies for Condor its service from Munich this winter, because Condor's 767s are undergoing heavy maintenance. Thomas Cook of UK is a permanent wet leaser to Condor (they are in the same holding). They provide aircraft and pilot crew, but Condor does fuel, maintenance and cabin crew. In the HiFly example above, HiFly provides full ACMI (aircraft crew maintenance insurance) for Condor.